# forçar um evento de um botão depois de excluir registro via modal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Quero forçar um clique no painel depois de excluir um registro via modal.

[![Descrição do Painel][1]][1]

Preciso que logo depois de excluir o arquivo, ele force o botão do painel.

```
$('#btnDelteYes').click(function () {
    var id = $('#myModalDelete').data('id');    

    $.post('estrutura/excluirarquivo.php',{acao:'delete',id:id},function(r) { 
       var m = jQuery.parseJSON(r);        
       if (m.success) {         
        toastr["success"](m.msg);
        $('#myModalDelete').modal('hide');
        //=====>>>> aquii
       } else {
        toastr["error"](m.msg);
        $('#myModalDelete').modal('hide');

       }
          hideMessage();
    });
});
```

Comment: Para fazer da maneira mais simples de todas coloque dentro 
do bloco de success a comando $("#IDBotao").trigger();
Você pode ver mais coisas a respeito do trigger http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ e implementar um evento customizado ou acionar só "click" $("#IDBotao").trigger("click");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está usando `Materialize`, basta fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$('#btnDelteYes').click(function () {
    var id = $('#myModalDelete').data('id');    

    $.post('estrutura/excluirarquivo.php',{acao:'delete',id:id},function(r) { 
       var m = jQuery.parseJSON(r);        
       if (m.success) {         
        toastr["success"](m.msg);
        $('#myModalDelete').modal('hide');

        /* Executa o evento de clique na "tab" */
        $("[href=\"#panel80\"]").click();


       } else {
        toastr["error"](m.msg);
        $('#myModalDelete').modal('hide');

       }
          hideMessage();
    });
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("#btn").click( function() {
  $("[href=\"#panel80\"]").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#panel80">Test 2</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
  <div id="panel80" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
  <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
  <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
</div>

<button id="btn" class="button">Acessar Tab 2</button>
```

Caso você queira atualizar a página, basta executar: `window.location.reload()`

Exemplo:

```
$('#btnDelteYes').click(function () {
    var id = $('#myModalDelete').data('id');    

    $.post('estrutura/excluirarquivo.php',{acao:'delete',id:id},function(r) { 
       var m = jQuery.parseJSON(r);        
       if (m.success) {         
        toastr["success"](m.msg);
        $('#myModalDelete').modal('hide');

        /* Recarrega a página */
        window.location.reload()


       } else {
        toastr["error"](m.msg);
        $('#myModalDelete').modal('hide');

       }
          hideMessage();
    });
});
```

Comment: Isso mesmo Valdeir, valeu pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Use o `trigger` passando o `click` como parâmetro.

```
 $('#btnDelteYes').click(function () {
    var id = $('#myModalDelete').data('id');    

    $.post('estrutura/excluirarquivo.php',{acao:'delete',id:id},function(r) { 
       var m = jQuery.parseJSON(r);        
       if (m.success) {         
        toastr["success"](m.msg);
        $('#myModalDelete').modal('hide');
        $('#seuBotao').trigger('click'); //id do seu botão
       } else {
        toastr["error"](m.msg);
        $('#myModalDelete').modal('hide');

       }
          hideMessage();
    });
});
```

```js
$('#bt2').click(function(){
    alert('botao 2 clicado');
})

$('#bt1').click(function(){
   $('#bt2').trigger('click');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bt1"> bt1 </button>
<button id="bt2" disabled> bt2 </button>
```

Comment: Não rolou, a tela ficou parada com o registro que foi excluido.
<li class="nav-item">
                                        <a id="btnpdf" class="nav-link waves-light waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel80" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br> ARQUIVOS PDF'S</a>
                                    </li>

Comment: Como não? editei o exemplo, coloquei outro abaixo que usa a função `trigger('click')`, veja ela em funcionamento.

Comment: Jorge, eu editei exatamente como vc indicou, porem não acontece nada, a tela fica com os mesmo registros, para atualizar eu precisa clicar no f5 ou clicar em outro painel e voltar para ele

Comment: Qual ação esse botão alvo do `trigger` está realizando?

Comment: esse é o botão. ele ja tem um identificador href="#panel80"
<li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link waves-light waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel80" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><br> ARQUIVOS PDF'S</a>
                                    </li>

Comment: jorge, descobri o problema, na verdade esta chegando no painel, o problema e outro, preciso refazer a consulta(sql) do painel, para que o registro excluido suma da tela.

Comment: Já esperava que o problema era na `função` executada nesse botão, sendo assim, marque a resposta certa que ajudou a solucionar o seu problema.